# Does AppleCare care if I've modded my machine?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, repair, applecare

I have a 15" MacBook Pro whose SuperDrive I have removed and added a ssd. It's been running well like this everyday for 30 months.

I was using it the other day, and the video started to freak out with a bunch of lines on the screen printer the computer crashed and now it won't boot. When I turn it on I got a bunch of video artifacts and then the machine stops.

Seems like a pretty cut and dry hardware failure to me. I'd like to take it in to Apple to have them replace the logic board, but I'm worried that they'll balk when they see the modifications I've made.

Do you think that it'll be an issue with them, or are they likely to recognize the problem as being unrelated to the changes I've made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally all changes you made yourself are not liked at Apple. They cancel your guarantee. But I don't think I will be an issue other than that. They will probably just replace it. I wouldn't tell them though, that you made these changes, because depending on how nice the person you get to repair your MacBook is, he'll maybe just ignore that you modified it, and maybe you have to pay less.

Comment: Can you clarify? It seems that some of your statements are contradicting. "They cancel your guarantee" vs. "they'll probably just replace it"

Comment: They WILL replace it, but modding your machine cancels the guarantee, so it may cost more with a modded machine, than with a non-modded machine. Is it clear now, or shall I edit my answer and try to make it clearer that way?

Answer (score 0):

It is Apple's discretion if the modification is the cause of the problem, in which case…

> The Plan does not apply to: […]
>
> (ii) Damage caused by
>
> (a) a product that is not the Covered Equipment,

Furthermore, Apple doesn't cover modified equipment anyway…

> (iii) Covered Equipment with a serial number that has been altered, defaced or removed, or has been modified to alter its functionality or capability without the written permission of the manufacturer;

<sup>Source: https://www.apple.com/legal/sales-support/applecare/appgeos.html</sup>